# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imports')

Tags: angular, node-modules

i create app in angular 17, Node.js v20.10.0 and all the to=ime i refresh  or save my app i get this error:
node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-68d1a114.js:45925
JSON.stringify(output.imports)),
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imports')
at file:///node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-68d1a114.js:45925:47
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to a bug in Vite https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9327 which is related to a bug in Nodes implementation of `cwd()`. Basically, Angular that is now using Vite, does not follow symlinks properly.

Solution is to only run program in the actual place on disk where the program resides and not from a symlinked path.